# Increase size of the partition

Tags: dual-boot, disk-usage, partitioning

I have following disk which include **Windows 8.1** and **Ubuntu 16.04** OPs.
I want to increase size of **partition 6** which is Ubuntu's system partition.
**I can't reinstall my system**, so I ask you guys if is there any way to do it?
We can decrease size of partition 4(WIN OS), partition 5 or partition 7 which would be the best way for me.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: If you'd post a full current-window-only gparted screenshot, I can give you a better recommendation. I need to also see used/free space, and any extended partitions.

Comment: @heynnema [gparted photo](http://imgur.com/a/43xFA)

Comment: Please see my completed answer, below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, increasing the size of sda6 is fairly easy. We'll **resize** and **move** sda7, then **resize** sda6.

## First backup all important data on sda6 and sda7!

- Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda7 in the lower pane and choose **resize**/move
- in the graphic representation shown in the upper pane, hover the mouse pointer over the right edge of sda7 and you'll see an arrow that you can click and drag
- drag the right edge of sda7 left to **resize** for as much space as you wish to add to sda6 (ie: 30G)
- hover the mouse pointer over the center of sda7 and you'll see a hand cursor that you can click and drag
- drag the sda7 partition to **move** it all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon
- right-click on sda6 in the lower pane and choose **resize**/move
- drag the right side of sda6 to **resize** it all the way to the right
- click the Apply icon
- you're done!
- reboot the computer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to run a live version of ubuntu (on an usb stick, for example) and run gparted. Then decrease the size of the partition 5 or 7, so you can increase size of partition 6. Backup before doing so!

Also a real quick search can easily get you some nice tutorials. Here's what I found in less than a minute:

- [How to Resize Your Ubuntu Partitions | How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/)
- [Modify Your Partitions With GParted Without Losing Data | How To Forge](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted)

Comment: I read a few of this kind of articles. I wonder what are the chances to screw up the system after resizing some of the partition in that way. Why everyone recommends to make back-up and do it on live-usb system?

Comment: How you do the backups is up to you and the end result is what matters. You need backups because any change to a partition has a risk of data loss.  Particularly in your case you'd be resizing 1 or 2 partitions and moving to the left and resizing a third, which increments the risk by a lot. You need a live session to resize partitions that otherwise would be in use, not for backups, and yes, there's always a chance of screwing up the dual boot.

Comment: However, if resizing Windows partitions that can and *should* be done in Windows, using Windows tools, reboot and run the error correction tool if the system doesn't asks for it right from the start. Then you're good to go and do the rest with GParted in a live session.